# Is it true that $\mathit{MA}(\omega_1)$ iff $\omega_1<\mathfrak{p}$?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, cardinal-characteristics, selection-principles

Recall that

$\mathfrak{p}=\min\{|F|: F$ is a subfamily of $[\omega]^{\omega}$ with the  *sfip* which has no infinite pseudo-intersection $\}$.

The cardinal $\mathfrak{q}_0$ defined as the smallest cardinality of a subset of $\mathbf{R}$ which is not a $Q$-space.

**Q1.** Is it true that $\mathit{MA}(\omega_1)$ iff $\omega_1<\mathfrak{p}$ ?

**Q2.** Is there a model of set theory in which $\omega_1=\mathfrak{q}_0$ and a non-$\mathit{MA}(\omega_1)$ ?

Comment: KP Hart has answered your questions here, but let me add that a good resource for lots of further information about related topics is David Fremlin's book "Consequences of Martin's Axiom".

Comment: @‍KPHart's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438583) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438579/is-it-true-that-ma-omega-1-iff-omega-1-mathfrakp#comment1130950_438579) by @AndreasBlass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Q1: No, see [Between Martin's Axiom and Souslin's Hypothesis](https://eudml.org/doc/211011) by Kunen and Tall. Note: Bell proved in [The combinatorial principle $P(\mathfrak{c})$](https://eudml.org/doc/211293) that $\mathfrak{p}>\aleph_1$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{MA}(\aleph_1)$ for $\sigma$-centered partial orders.

Q2: $\mathsf{MA}(\aleph_1)$, even $\mathfrak{p}>\aleph_1$, implies $\mathfrak{q_0}>\aleph_1$, see page 162 of [Internal Cohen Extensions](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(70)90009-4) by Martin and Solovay. The principle $\mathsf{S}_\aleph$ is proved on page 154, using a $\sigma$-centered partial order.
So, every model with $\mathfrak{q}_0=\aleph_1$ satisfies $\neg\mathsf{MA}(\aleph_1)$ as well, for example every model of $\mathsf{CH}$ will do.

Comment: Superb answer. It would be nice if you could add a referece for your second answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, a link to the second answer would be very helpful.

Comment: I added two more references, to make the picture complete.

Comment: Many thanks! Very helpful  references !